# Convert dd-mm-yyyy / dd/mm/yyyy string to date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am trying to convert a string format of date into a date object in JavaScript.
I am getting different kinds of date formats like "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" or "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" or "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss" etc. I want to convert them into timestamp and display them in UI. 
I tried below code for getting date object

```
new Date("05/01/2012 21:10:17");
Tue May 01 2012 21:10:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
new Date("15/01/2012 21:10:17");
Invalid Date
new Date("15-01-2012 21:10:17");
Invalid Date
new Date("05-01-2012 21:10:17");
Tue May 01 2012 21:10:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Few of them are getting `Invalid Date`. Please help me, is there any specific code/logic to convert any string format to date object?

Comment: If those dates are strings, how do you tell if 01-05-2000 is the fifth of January or the first of May? How would you tell the program how to tell the difference?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `Date` object reads `"month day year"`, not `"day month year"`, so you need to update your `String` a bit.

Here, I just swap the month and the day in your String :

```js
const data = "15/01/2012 21:10:17";
const readableDate = data.substring(3,6) + data.substring(0,2) + data.substring(5,data.length);
console.log(new Date(readableDate));
```

Comment: The built-in parser is only required to support the [subset of ISO 8601](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) noted in ECMA-262, support for any other format is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

There is the best tool for playing with dates in JavaScript I've been ever using. It's called [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). I recommend you to take a look at this, it allows you for example to do something like this:

```
var date = moment("2014-02-27T10:00:00").format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var dateMonthAsWord = moment("2014-02-27T10:00:00").format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
var myDate = moment(str, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate();
```

Comment: This should be a comment. Answers of "use library X" when the library isn't tagged or mentioned in the OP [aren't helpful](https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: I don't agree. It's useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);
```

To convert to timestamp you call:

```
d.getTime()
```